# Is 2(6)3 (2↑↑↑↑3) equal to 2^65536? And if yes, is 2(n)3 equal to 2 to the power of how many time 2 is repeated in the power tower?

Tags: big-numbers, power-towers, hyperoperation

I am writing a paper for the last digits in a chain power of 2. I was wondering if 2↑↑↑↑3 is 2^65536. Beacouse 2↑↑↑3 is 65536 or 2^**16** and is written as 2^2^...2^2 **16** times and 2↑↑3 is 16 or 2^**4** and is written as 2^...2^2 **4** times.

Comment: Carefully study the Knut-uparrow-notation. It usually produces numerical "monsters", $$3\uparrow \uparrow\uparrow 3$$ for example is already a power tower of $3^{27}$ $3's$. In particular note that the calculation must be done from right ( or above in the case of a power tower) which makes the results so large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$2\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 3=2\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 2\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 2=2\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 4=2\uparrow\uparrow2\uparrow\uparrow\ 2\uparrow \uparrow 2=2\uparrow \uparrow 2\uparrow \uparrow 4=2\uparrow \uparrow 65536$$

So , your number is a power tower of $65536$ $2's$ , much larger than $2^{65536}$